# Does Suryanamaskar contain all yoga's benefit?

Tags: yoga

I have heard that doing Suryanamaskar everyday gives us most of or all of benefits of all kinds yogas.

Does it really Suryanamaskar so powerful which will give us most of benefits of yogas.

So if we really do suryanamaskar regularly everyday , does we needed to do other yoga or not ?

Comment: You can go through the material at the following lnk (  https://www.artofliving.org/in-en/yoga/yoga-poses/sun-salutation).  For having in depth understanding,  please contact a competent Yoga Guru

Comment: (Telling you from experience) SuryaNamaskar is a powerful practice but it does not have all the benefits of Yoga. Consider it as more of an elaborated warm-up full-body exercise. If you see some Yoga videos you will notice that it is usually one of the first exercises being performed. If you only get 10 mins to do Yoga, you can do Suryanamaskar, but if you have time, other practices must be done for better results

Comment: by yoga, do u only mean Asana and Pranayama? or all 8 parts of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surya Namaskar is considered the ‘king’ of asana practice. It is a beautiful weave of the physical, emotional/psychological, spiritual aspects of our being.
Surya Namaskar has various exercises for the whole body & it contain total 12 yoga through which we have exercise for out whole body but we can not say that surya namsakar has all benefits of all yogas.

There are other benefits of surya namaskar like below.

When combined with appropriate breathing, it works on the deeper physiology of the body, the very endocrine system, whose synchronized functioning is responsible for the health of our body and emotions.
It works on the various chakras or energy vortices at the etheric level.
When the bija and the surya mantras are chanted while moving the body in tandem with the breath, the frequency of the entire system can be altered to vibrate at a much higher level.
When performed in its completeness, Surya Namaskar has the capacity to change our very bio-energy by cleansing, healing and rejuvenating us at the deepest cellular level.
Surya Namaskar helps in overall personality development and works at three levels namely physical, mental and when practiced with chanting of mantras it works at a spiritual level too.
It is a profoundly simple practice that brings together the body-mind-spirit to confer a feeling of expanded Oneness with all. It represents the masculine energy of activity and is done first thing in the morning as the sun rises in the horizon.

Doing Surya namaskar in early morning with porper breathing technique & chanting give maximum benefits to our body.